# Overloading [] and = operator for generic array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have created a generic array class in c++ .Using this i  want to overload  [] and = operators.
Such that I can initialize array elements like 
array a1;
a1[2]=77;
How can this be done?
Here is my code:

```
tempate<class T>
class array
{
 T *data;
 int length;
 public:
 array()
 {
 length=0;
 }
 array(int data)
 {
 data=new T(data);
 length=data;
 }
 T operator[](int a)
 {
 return *(data+A);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your operator needs to return a reference. Best to also have a constant version:

```
T & operator[](std::size_t i) { return data[i]; }
T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
```

Comment: +1: `std::size_t` type is more correct than `int` in the context of operator[]

Comment: I'd stick an `assert` in there too

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is being done by returning a reference, i.e., something like this:

```
T& operator[](int a)
{
    return *(data+a);
}
```

Also, to allow access from const context, you also should provide a const version:

```
const T& operator[](int a) const
{
    return *(data+a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

avoid code repetition:

```
const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return data[pos];
}

T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
{
    return const_cast<T&>(static_cast<const T&>(*this)[pos]);
}
```